# Gregorian days to Julian days (Loop over a list)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, time

I'm trying to convert from Gregorian dates to Julian days reading a list of days from a csv file. This is the code I've so far:

```
import date time
import csv
import math
import numpy

data = open('tmp2')

month, day = [ ], [ ], [ ]

for index, line in enumerate(data.readlines( )):

    year.append(int(line.split(",")[0]))
    month.append(int(line.split(",")[1]))
    day.append(int(line.split(",")[2])) 

 for y, d, m in zip(year, day, month):
     DJ= d - 32075 + 1461*(y + 4800 + (m -14)/12) / 4 + 367*(m - 2 - ( m - 14 ) / 12 * 12 ) / 12 - 3*((y + 4900 + ( m -14) / 12 ) / 100) / 4

 print DJ
```

But I got this as a result:

```
  2456177
  2456177
```

Basically just two values. The csv file has the next structure:

```
 2012,7,09
 2012,7,11
 2012,8,11
 2012,8,12
 2012,8,14
 2012,9,19
 2012,9,20
 2012,9,23
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the file in, and operate on it line-by-line as you are reading. Also there is no need to zip something, then immediately unpack it. Also you can `map` the values to `int` so you can operate on them

```
with open('tmp2', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        y, m, d = map(int, line.split(','))
        DJ = d - 32075 + 1461*(y + 4800 + (m -14)/12) / 4 + 367*(m - 2 - ( m - 14 ) / 12 * 12 ) / 12 - 3*((y + 4900 + ( m -14) / 12 ) / 100) / 4
        print DJ
```

Output (I don't know if this is correct, I just used your formula)

```
2456119
2456121
2456152
2456153
2456155
2456191
2456192
2456195
```